# Python - Matplotlib plots incorrect graph when using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, data-analysis

(My first ever StackOverflow question)

I'm trying to plot bitcoin's market-cap against the date using pandas and matplotlib in Python.

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read in CSV file using Pandas built in method
df = pd.read_csv("btc.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Here are some details about the data frame:
[dataframe details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nmyn.jpg)

matplotlib code:

```
#Plot marketcap(usd)
plt.plot(df.index, df["marketcap(USD)"])
plt.show()
```

Result: 
[Incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzjo3.jpg)

The plot seems to be more like scribbles that seem to move backwards. How could I fix this?

Comment: Looks like your data is not sorted by the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your Pandas Series "marketcap(USD)" directly using:

```
df["marketcap(USD)"].plot()
```

See the Pandas documentation on [Basic Plotting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot)